# Cannot import "logging" module using Jython in embedded Jetty -> ImportError: no os specific module found

Tags: jython, importerror

I'm trying to use Jython (embedded) in a Jetty server (all through Maven) to invoke a simple Python script.

My script works fine as long as I don't try to use any of the standard library's such as 'logging.'  Whenever I try to import one of the standard library's it fails with the exception "ImportError."

**The exception I get is:**

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\home\work\sample\content\helloworld\helloworld.py", line 10, in <module>
    import logging
  File "c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import sys, os, types, time, string, cStringIO, traceback
  File "c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\os.py", line 119, in <module>
    raise ImportError, 'no os specific module found'
ImportError: no os specific module found

    at org.python.core.PyException.fillInStackTrace(PyException.java:70)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:181)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:29)
    at java.lang.RuntimeException.<init>(RuntimeException.java:32)
    at org.python.core.PyException.<init>(PyException.java:46)
    at org.python.core.PyException.doRaise(PyException.java:200)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1159)
    at org.python.core.Py.makeException(Py.java:1163)
    at os$py.f$0(c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\os.py:692)
    at os$py.call_function(c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\os.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:325)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:144)
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:504)
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:410)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:620)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:650)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:741)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:791)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1236)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:367)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1207)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1190)
    at org.python.core.imp.importOne(imp.java:802)
    at logging$py.f$0(c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\logging\__init__.py:1372)
    at logging$py.call_function(c:\home\work\sample\content\Lib\logging\__init__.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:325)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:144)
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:504)
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:410)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:620)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_first(imp.java:650)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:741)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:791)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1236)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:367)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1207)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1190)
    at org.python.core.imp.importOne(imp.java:802)
    at helloworld.helloworld$py.f$0(c:\home\work\sample\content\helloworld\helloworld.py:19)
    at helloworld.helloworld$py.call_function(c:\home\work\sample\content\helloworld\helloworld.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:325)
    at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:144)
    at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:504)
    at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:410)
    at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:109)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:622)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_name(imp.java:761)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:791)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1236)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:367)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1207)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:869)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:845)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1.f$0(<string>:1)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx1.call_function(<string>)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
    at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1241)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:138)
```

**My scripts looks like:**

```
from java.util import Random
from java.util import Date

import sys

print(sys.path)
print(sys.builtin_module_names)

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
logger1 = logging.getLogger('aaa') 
logger1.warning('************* This message comes from one module') 

def say_hello():
        return 'hello world1'
```

**I've tried the following so far but nothing has worked:**

- Include the zip of the 'Lib' directory in my classpath
- Hard-coding the 'Lib' path when i setup the interpreter.

If I do it directly from the interactive Jython shell the script works fine (and a logging message appears).

Thanks.

KJQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for now i've found an answer to my own question...

Basically, i knew it had something to do with my paths but could not figure out how to do them.

I ended up creating a "standalone" version of the Jython jar through the installer (and it includes the /Libs directory) and using that.